# need to add .css to a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to add some css to a class. This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tech').css({ "border-bottom": "dotted 1px #0860a8", "text-decoration": "none" });
    $('.tech').Tooltip(onMouseEnter) 
});
```

Its not working. What can I do to show up for all class="tech"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a dot...

```
$('.tech').css({ 
         "border-bottom": "dotted 1px #0860a8", 
         "text-decoration": "none" 
});
```

To select a class, use .classname and to select an id, use #id respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('.tech').css({ "border-bottom": "dotted 1px #0860a8", "text-decoration": "none" });
```

(note the period before tech)